# How to put visibility: visible on this slideshow script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I asked a question related to this one previously but I need to know how to put "visibility: visible;" for this type of slideshow:

http://www.efectorelativo.net/laboratory/viewer/

We're using "Sample 5."

I placed "visibility: hidden;" for the class "box5."

What I like to happen is for the slideshow's visibility to be initially hidden. Then when the javascript is finally loaded, that's the only time the photos/text would be shown.

The reason for this is that when the page is still loading, the group of images and text we used for the slideshow kind of overlaps and is quite ugly (it only shows for about 3 seconds before the javascript is finally loaded to show only 1 group of image and text at a time).

How do I insert the "visibility: visible;" inside the jQuery script? This is the direct link to the script:

http://www.efectorelativo.net/laboratory/viewer/_class.viewer.packed.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work:

$(function(){
        $('#ID').css('visibility','visible');
    });

or

```
$('#ID').css({visibility:'visible'});
```

if you don't know the ID of the element you want to make visible, use a different jquery selector.